# Dropdown list not the same height with different css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site with the Slate bootstrap theme installed.

When I add a dropdown with a actio button, the height of the dropdown is not the same as the action button.

If I try the same with the base theme comming from bootstrap it work.

Both exemple use this code

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <select id="listEmployee" class="form-control valid">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">This button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With Bootstrap default theme
[image]
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edc1dzsj/1/)

With Boostrap Slate theme
[image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xedw9cqg/)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Both have the same height. The `Default Theme` has both the `Select and Button` of height `34px` and `Slate Theme` with `38px`.

Comment: @TusharKhatiwada But the Slate button appear not to be the same height  as the dropdown

Comment: They have the same height. Instead the top-left and bottom-left corners of the button don't have a `border-radius`. So it seems like it's slightly taller than the `Dropdown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a border to the button it self.

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */

body {
  margin: 10px;
}
.btn.btn-default.btn-border,
.btn.btn-default.btn-border:hover,
.btn.btn-default.btn-border:focus {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://bootswatch.com/slate/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown active"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Getting started <b class="caret"></b></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download">Download Bootstrap</a>

            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Examples</li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template">Basic template</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/">Starter template</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/">Grids</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/">Jumbotron</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/">Navbar</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/">Sign-in page</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/">Sticky footer</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/">Offcanvas</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/">Carousel</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/">Theme</a>

            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Compatibility</li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration">Migrating from 2.x to 3.0</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers">Browser support</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties">Third party support</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/css">CSS</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/components">Components</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">JavaScript</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/customize">Customize</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select id="listEmployee" class="form-control valid">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-border">This button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the `form-control` class that the heights are defined differently.

default

```
.form-control {
  height: 34px;
}
```

Slate

```
.form-control {
  height: 38px;
}
```

To override it, do

```
#listEmployee.form-control {
  height: 34px; //or whatever height you want
}
```

Comment: If I change the height the dropdown is higher than the button and missaligned

Comment: then change the height of the button

Answer (score 1):

Actually they are of the same height, but button has a border of similar color than the background, that makes looks like a lower height for the button.

look at the image:

[image]

Comment: Just change the border color.